# Can't use CSS class when there are 3 similar names

Tags: html, css, flask

Whenever I have 3 classes with similar names, one of them gets dropped. The CSS class doesn't even show up in the Firefox Style Editor, the definition of it is completely removed. I have no clue why this could be happening. It could be Flask, which is what I'm using to serve the webpage, but I don't think that's the problem. Here are the CSS classes I am talking about:

```css
.alert_success{                                                                 
    margin: auto;                                                               
    background-color: rgba(30,77,42,10);                                        
    border-radius: 4px;                                                         
    height: 50px;                                                               
    width: 45%;                                                                 
    border: 1px solid rgba(60,120,73,10);                                       
    margin-top: 20px;                                                           
}                                                                               
                                                                                 
.alert_failed{                                                                  
    margin: auto;                                                               
    background-color: rgba(80,20,42,10);                                        
    border-radius: 4px;                                                         
    height: 50px;                                                               
    width: 45%;                                                                 
    border: 1px solid rgba(110,53,53,10);                                       
    margin-top: 20px;                                                           
}                                                                               
                                                                                 
.alert_info{                                                                    
    margin: auto;                                                               
    background-color: rgba(60,65,100,10);                                       
    border-radius: 4px;                                                         
    height: 50px;                                                               
    width: 45%;                                                                 
    border: 1px solid rgba(53,53,110,10);                                       
    margin-top: 20px;                                                           
}
```

Comment: _"Whenever I have 3 classes with similar names, one of them gets dropped."_ Dropped from what?  The CSS file?  An element that they are applied to?  I think you may need to provide more context for this to be answerable...  Perhaps show the source code and the output?

Comment: I would check your Python code in Flask that's rendering your HTML. In my experience this usually happens because you've missed a quote where you're outputting the class name

Comment: @AlexanderNied I mentioned in my post that the definition is completely removed from Style Editor.

Comment: @dave Same thing as what I said to Nied. I couldn't be that I forgot a quote since it didn't even show up in the Style Editor. I even tested using all of the classes and removing one from the class definitions. If I removed the alert_failed, the alert_info starts working, and when I add alert_failed back, it doesn't show up, despite working before I removed it. I have no clue why.

Comment: I understand it doesn't show up in the style editor, but that doesn't tell us what is happening programatically-- this is a _symptom_, but to solve it we need the _root cause_.  It sounds like you have tried applying the classes to elements but you are not seeing the styles applied-- have you looked at the CSS file that is being served?  Is it being served at all?  If you look in the contents, are these styles not where you would expect them to be?  Noting that it is not in the style editor is like saying a person "has a fever"-- it doesn't tell you what is _causing_ the fever.

Comment: Yes your CSS looks fine. If you share the HTML that's output in your browser and your view in Flask we can help further